# How to add some values of an array to another new array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Hi i had some code to find the odd numbers from dynamic array

**Code**

```
System.out.print("Odd numbers:");
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Now i want to add this result in new array, So, please help me

Comment: are you using an array or a list(arraylist)? Have you attempted anything?

Comment: It isn't very hard create another array and add the elements to the new array...

Comment: @depperm I am using array

Comment: @StackUser you may need to use `arraylist `..if you use `array` you have to loop 2 times ,1st to find required length for new array.

Comment: @Fast Snail I know how to do it by using arraylist, please tell me by using array

Comment: You can just create another array of the same size add the elements then trim the array...

Comment: @brso05 that's a good solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.print("Odd numbers:");
for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 2 != 0) {
  result.add(a[i]);
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```